# bundles get installed on both Karaf instances

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, karaf, dosgi

I want to make a "communication" between two **Karaf** instances and I decided to use **Karaf Cellar** in order to do that.

I, now, have two bundles each one is installed on a Karaf container. They are identified by an address and port provided in **hazelcast.xml.**

My problem is when I **restart** both Karaf containers I have bundles which are installed on Karaf (A) that got installed on Karaf (B) and vice versa.

Now I have the same bundles installed on **both** Karaf containers.

Is there anyway to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was in the **org.apache.karaf.cellar.groups.cfg** file.

Had to set **default.bundle.sync** value to **disabled** and not **cluster**.